# SQL - lock select check

Tags: sql, oracle, select, locking

I created a locks on 3 sessions a database record-TX table.

Next I wrote a query to check the locks on the database Oracle but something is not right:

```
select 
    round(s1.seconds_in_wait/60,1) as TIME, s1.event,
    s1.blocking_session as SID_A, s1.username as USER_A, 
    s2.sid as SID_B, s2.username as USER_B  
from 
    v$session  s1, v$session s2   
where
     s1.blocking_session is not null 
     and s1.seconds_in_wait > 1  
     and s1.sid = s2.sid  
order by 
     s1.seconds_in_wait desc;
```

Result:

```
| Time | Evetn              |SID_A| USER_A  |SID_B| USER_B  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|10.1 | enq: TX row lock.. |  45 | Schema1 |  54 | Schema1 |
|15.5 | enq: TX row lock.. |  45 | Schema2 |  95 | Schema2 |
```

Rather it should be something like this:

```
| Time | Evetn              |SID_A| USER_A  |SID_B| USER_B  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|10.1 | enq: TX row lock.. |  45 | Schema1 |  54 | Schema2 |
|15.5 | enq: TX row lock.. |  45 | Schema1 |  95 | Schema3 |
```

Where is the problem please help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 3):

You join on `s1.sid=s2.sid` - that will join the row with itself. I think you want to join using the blocking sid:

```
select 
    round(s1.seconds_in_wait/60,1) as TIME, s1.event,
    s1.sid as SID_A, s1.username as USER_A, 
    s2.sid as SID_B, s2.username as USER_B  
from 
    v$session  s1, v$session s2   
where
     s1.blocking_session is not null 
     and s1.seconds_in_wait > 1  
     and s1.blocking_session = s2.sid  
order by 
     s1.seconds_in_wait desc;
```

Or (using ansi joins):

```
select 
    round(s1.seconds_in_wait/60,1) as TIME, s1.event,
    s1.sid as SID_A, s1.username as USER_A, 
    s2.sid as SID_B, s2.username as USER_B  
from 
    v$session  s1
join
    v$session s2   
on
    s1.blocking_session = s2.sid  
where
     s1.blocking_session is not null 
     and s1.seconds_in_wait > 1  
order by 
     s1.seconds_in_wait desc;
```